# how to activate python3 in Google-cloud-data

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-datalab

I am using Python3 for my projects. However, the Google Cloud Datalab runs with Python2.7.x by default. How do I change to Python3?

Answer (score 3):

Datalab only supports Python 2 for now unfortunately.

One thing you can try is install the [Pydatalab lib](https://github.com/googledatalab/pydatalab), which is a Jupyter extension that adds support for a number of Google Cloud Platform services to your Jupyter notebooks. That library [supports Python 3](https://github.com/googledatalab/pydatalab/commit/14ce30b205caf7d132694c59333c849828c9fae7).

Comment: I see that Datalab now has Python3 support. However, when I install a package such as ```!pip install bson``` it only installs for python 2. How can I change the environment to python3 for a notebook?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that they support Python 3 now:
https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/issues/902 .

Comment: Actually, I've customized Datalab image to enable Python3 and add some libraries. See https://hub.docker.com/r/vochicong/datalab-nlp/ and https://github.com/vochicong/datalab-nlp!